# Kendo ui grid and knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-grid

Can we dynamically change the column hidden property using knockout js? I 
am returning column and data in the same datasource. 
Initially the column is visible, when the data loads the column hidden property returned is true.But still not reflecting and column is visible

Can anyone please guide me

Comment: Provide the sample code for this  or create fiddler example so everyone get a look into that and help you

Comment: Are you using jQuery as well?